# Verbatim invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: packages, verbatim

can someone pls help and show me whats wrong with this. I'm a complete latex noob. Sorry that the text is written in german. The Code shouldnt be the problem I have another file, written in the same way, which compiles without problem. Guess the problem is with texmaker.

Always get the Error message: ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\title{Maß- und Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie Blatt 1}
\author{}
\date{5. Mai 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Aufgabe 5}


Output:
\verbatiminput{Blatt02.R}
Source Code:

\section*{Aufgabe 6}
\subsection*{i.)}
$\emptyset$ ist endlich 
\[\Rightarrow \emptyset ^c=\Omega \in \mathcal{F}\]
Sei $A\in \mathcal{F}$, nach Konstruktion von $\mathcal{F}$ $\Rightarrow A^c\in \mathcal{F}$
\\Sei $A_n \in \mathcal{F}, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ und $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ mit $i \in I\Rightarrow A_i$ abzählbar. Wir definieren zudem noch $J:=\mathbb(N)\backslash I$, $A:=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i$ und $B:=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J} A_J$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&B=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J} A_J\\
\Rightarrow & B^c=\bigcap\limits_{j\in J} A_j^c\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Da abzählbare Vereinigungen und Schnitte von abzählbaren Mengen wieder abzählbar sind, sind $A$ und $B^c$ oder $B$ (Im Fall $B=\emptyset $) abzählbar und damit:
\[A,B \in \mathcal{F}\]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n=A \cup B\\ 
\Rightarrow & (\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n)^c=A^c \cap B^c
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
mit $A^c, B^c \in \mathcal{F}\Rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in \mathcal{F}$
\newline $\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ ist $\sigma$ -Algebra
\newline $\emptyset$ ist endlich 
\[\mu(\emptyset)=0.\]
Da $\mu(\mathcal{F}={0,1}$ ist (M2) offensichtlich erfüllt.
Sei $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$ mit $A,B$ überabzählbar und $A\neq B^c$. Angenommen $A\cap B=\emptyset$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Rightarrow & (A\cap B)^c=\Omega \\
\Rightarrow & A^c \cup B^c = \Omega\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Da $A^c,B^c$ abzählbar und $\Omega$ überabzählbar haben wir einen Wiederspruch zur Annahme. Also sind zwei überabzählbare Mengen in $\mathcal{F}$ nie disjunkt. Mit der Aussage, dass abzählbare Vereinigungen von abzählbaren Mengen wieder abzählbar sind und eine beliebige abzählbare Menge mit einer überabzählbaren Menge vereinigt wieder eine überabzählbare Menge ergibt,  folgt dann dass (M3) erfüllt ist.
Damit ist $\mu$ ein Maß auf $\mathcal{F}$.

\subsection*{ii.)}
$\{1 \} $ erzeugt $\mathcal{P}(\{ 0,1 \} )$ auf $\{0,1\} .$
\[ \varphi^{-1}( \{ 1\})=\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{F} \]
Dann folgt nach Satz 1.20 $\varphi$ messbar. Sei $A \in \mathcal{P}(\{ 0,1 \} )$
\[\mu_\varphi(A)=\mu(\varphi^{-1}(A)=
\begin{cases} 
     1 &, \varphi^{-1}(A) \text{ überabzählbar} \\
     0 &, \text{ sonst} 
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases} 
     1 &, 1 \in A \\
     0 &, 1 \not\in A 
\end{cases}
\]


\newpage
\section*{Aufgabe 8}
Sei $\varepsilon>0, \delta>0$ und $x \in U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon}$

\[\Rightarrow  \exists y,z \in B_\delta(x) : d_2(f(y),f(x))>\varepsilon\]
\[\Rightarrow  d_1(x,y)<\delta \wedge d_1(x,z)<\delta\]
Sei $j:= \max(d_1(x,y),d_1(x,z))<\delta$ und $\alpha \in \left] 0,\delta-j\right[ \neq \emptyset$ 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Rightarrow & B_\alpha (x) \subset B_\delta (x) \wedge (\forall a \in B_\alpha (x): d_1(a,y)<\delta \wedge d_1(a,z)<\delta ) \\
\Rightarrow & y,z \in B_\delta(a), \ \forall a \in B_\alpha(x)\\
\Rightarrow & B_\alpha(x) \in U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$\Rightarrow U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon}$ offen und $U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon} \in \mathcal{B}$
\newline $f$ in $x \in \Omega_1$ nicht stetig
\[\Leftrightarrow \exists\varepsilon>0,\forall\delta>0\exists y \in B_\delta(x): d_2(f(x),f(y))>\varepsilon\]
\[\Leftrightarrow \exists\varepsilon>0,\forall\delta>0\exists y,z \in B_\delta(x): d_2(f(z),f(y))>\varepsilon \ \ \ (*)\]
Wenn man sich (*) anschaut, sieht man dann wie man $U_f$ aus den   $U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon}$ konstruieren kann.
\[U_f\overset{!}{=}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}U_f^{\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{n}}\]
Sei $x \in U_f$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Leftrightarrow & \exists\varepsilon>0,\forall\delta>0\exists y,z \in B_\delta(x): d_2(f(z),f(y))>\varepsilon \\
\Leftrightarrow & \exists\varepsilon>0,\forall\delta>0: x \in U_f^{\delta,\varepsilon}\ \ \ \ (**) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
da für $a>b>0$ und $c>d>0$ gilt: $U_f^{a,d}\subset U_f^{a,c} \wedge U_f^{a,d}\subset U_f^{b,d}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(**)\Leftrightarrow & \exists\varepsilon>0\exists n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ mit } \frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon,\forall k\in \mathbb{N} : x \in U_f^{\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{n}}\\
\Leftrightarrow & \exists n\in\mathbb{N}: x \in \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}U_f^{\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{n}}\\
\Leftrightarrow & x\in\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}U_f^{\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{n}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Damit ist $U_f$ die abzählbare Vereinigung von abzählbaren Schnitten von Mengen in $\mathcal{B}$ \[\Rightarrow U_f \in \mathcal{B}\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I deleted my not helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted is valid UTF-8 (as the site always serves UTF-8) but your original file is not. Most likely it is in a legacy 8-bit encoding such as latin-1 (iso-8859-1) in which case, you could use

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

to tell LaTeX to use that encoding or (better) use your editor to re-save the file in UTF-8.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.The  re-save worked, you really saved my ass.